# JPA ManyToMany extra composite id

Tags: java, jpa

I try to create a ManytoMany relation anotation where the db already struture is fixed,

Class A Like the following

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A
 @Id
 @Column(name="A_ID")
 private Long a_id;
 ....//some other attributes

 @ManyToMany
 @JoinTable(name="A_B", 
      joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="A_ID"),         
      inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="B_ID")
 )
 @OrderColumn(name="SORT_ORDER")
 @LazyCollection(value=LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
 private List<B> bList = new ArrayList<B>();
 public List<B> getBList () {
     return bList ;
 }
 public void setBList (List<B> bList ) {
      this.bList = bList ;
 }
```

Class B as following:

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "B")
 public class B{

@Id
@Column(name="B_ID")
private Long b_id;
 ....//some other attributes

 }
```

And the manyToMany Table Class A_B has already build

```
 A_ID   B_ID     SORT_ORDER
 a1     b1        0
 a1     b1        1
 a1     b2        2
 a1     b1        3

 a2     b2        0
 a2     b3        1
 a2     b1        2
 a2     b2        3
 a2     b3        4
// where a_id, b_id and sort_order are composite key
```

How can I make the annotation to achieve the following objective

1. In class A, get the list of B with sort order
2. Save Class A, also persist Class A_B

Thank you

Comment: If this is M-N then you need Collection in both A and B. And what is the sort order, defined at which side? If this is a List at both sides then each side would have an order.

Comment: the sort_order is depend on ClassA, I want when load Class A, can have a list<Class B> in sort_order

Comment: update your classes to include Collection at both sides before you go any further. There is no relationship as you have it there right now. And if you have a list at the other side then you potentially have a sort order for that side too.

Comment: I haved updated the code, the collection can be at only one side